# How to integrate Acid-State's Template Haskell into your own template haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a template haskell library for my own use that generates functions. What I would like to do is pass these generated functions to acid-state's makeAcidic TH function.

However, the result of simply passing the generated name in my Q context results in this error:

is not in scope at a reify

How do I put my freshly created functions in scope for makeAcidic to work?

My code:

```
gen_render :: Name -> Q [Dec]
gen_render typName =
  do (TyConI d) <- reify typName -- Get all the information on the type
     (type_name, vars, nars, constructors) <- typeInfo (return d) -- extract name and constructors
     x <- mapM func_def constructors
     let funcs = concat x
     let setterNames = [setter | (setter, _) <- funcs]
     acidic <- makeAcidic typName setterNames
     return $ [newFuncs | (_, newFuncs) <- funcs] ++ acidic

     where func_def data_con@(con_name, compontents) 
               = do 
                   x <- mapM genFieldSetandGet compontents
                   return $ concat x
           genFieldSetandGet (Just fieldName, fieldType) = do

                   uVar <- runQ $ varE $ mkName "u"

                   ixInsert <- appsE $ [[| IxSet.insert |], (varE $ mkName "u"), parensE $ appsE [(varE fieldName), (varE $ mkName "db")]]

                   {-instanceD (cxt [])
                     (conT (mkName "DatabaseAccess") `appT` (return fieldType) `appT` conT typName)-}

                   let setterName = (mkName $ "updateDb" ++ (capitalize $ nameBase fieldName))

                   func <- funD setterName $
                               [clause [(varP $ mkName "u"), (varP $ mkName "db")] (normalB $ 
                                   [| modify |] `appE` [| IxSet.insert |] `appE` (varE $ mkName "u") ) []]

                   return [(setterName, func)]
```

Comment: It might help us if you showed us the relevant part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to ensure their splices are run before the makeAcidic splice.